# Поиск родительского тэга внутри файла через условие дочернего тэга bash

Tags: xml, bash, sed, grep

есть такая проблема на bash. Имеется xml-файл с множеством записей схожей структуры, например:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>

<operation id="73583876586">
      <card number_7813="8798505809">
         <commons:card_state
               status="ACTIVE"
         />
      </card>
   </operation>

...много аналогичных записей с некоторым отличием по тегам внутри...

<operation id="73584313194">
      <summary>
         <summary_item
               unit="BNS_NET"
               before="4182.0"
               amount="-4000.0"
               after="182.0"/>
      </summary>
      <payment_info>
         <payment_item type="points" amount="4000.0"/>
      </payment_info>
      <card number_7813="9646595694"
      >
         <commons:card_state
               status="ACTIVE"
         />
      </card>
   </operation>
```

Мне требуется найти все записи, которые содержат, например, payment_item, а после вытащить весь родительский тэг `<operation>` и все, что внутри него.

Проблема возникла в том, что я, найдя нужный мне кусок(а их может быть много, файл большой), не могу понять, как мне вытащить весь верхний тэг с ним.

Через sed не получилось - обрезалась только первая запись, остальные не обработались корректно.

Через grep с указанием -A и -B тоже не выходит, поскольку количество строк до родительского тэга может отличаться.

Через xmllint,xml и xmlstarlet у меня не получилось(возможно, руки из жопы, возможно кривой xml-формат в этом файле,возможно,проблема в макбуке)

Comment: Думаю это не совсем то, что нужно и не совсем bash это, но можете попробовать вот так `grep "<operation id=" ./test.txt | while read line; do a=$(awk "/$line/,/<\/operation>/" ./test.txt); [[ $(grep -o "payment_item" <<< "$a") != '' ]] && echo "$a"; done`

Comment: Не сработало, вообще ничего не нашлось...

Comment: имя к файлу в двух местах указали?

Comment: Разумеется, вместо text.txt указал полный путь до своего файла, не помогло(

Comment: @PotroNik, ну уже не смешно. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2511795

Comment: @0andriy, я и не смеюсь, во-первых, варианты которые вы предлагаете верные, никто не спорит. Но есть случаи, когда нет доступа к репозиторию для установки обновления, нет прав на установку пакета программ, и т.д. А во-вторых я предлагаю варианты, кому-то могут они помочь, если по той или иной причине не получится установить специализированное ПО.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, обрабатывать xml текстовыми средствами — это боль.

Во-вторых, в приведённый пример действительно не является корректным xml-документом: XML допускает только один корневой элемент, т.е. правильно его будет записать как-то так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<operation_list>
    <operation id="73583876586">
      <!-- ... -->
    </operation>
    <operation id="73584313194">
      <!-- ... -->
      <payment_info>
        <payment_item type="points" amount="4000.0"/>
      </payment_info>
    </operation>
</operation_list>
```

сделать это можно, например, `sed`'ом:

```
sed -i "$(echo -e '1a<operation_list>\n$a</operation_list>')" foo.xml
```

После этого его можно обрабатывать специализированными xml-утилитами, например `xpath`:

```
xpath -e '//operation[*/payment_item]' foo.xml
```

`xmllint` в этом отношении тоже применим, но хуже т.к. он не сможет переварить некоторые другие мелкие ошибки, например то, что пространство имён `commons` не определено. Про `xmlstarlet` я сказать ничего не могу т.к. не пользовался оным... Также могу посоветовать для обработки xml'я перейти на что-то посерьёзней bash'а из серии перло-пыхо-питона.

Comment: Отличный ответ!

Comment: Да, огромное спасибо) Так сработало!